# How can I add a thick border top to an entire row in excel using openxml

Tags: excel, openxml-sdk

I was looking through the productivity sdk tool and noticed it sets ThickTop attribute in the rows class to true.

So I did the following but nothing worked

```cs
worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>()
              .Elements<Row>().First(row => row.RowIndex == targetRow).ThickTop = true;
```

Comment: Do you have copy of excel? Create a spreadsheet use excel to format the document, save it and look at the xml in the produced document. That's what I always do. :-)

Comment: That's what i did in order to come up with the code snippet above.